# yum is broken because of missing Python module (RHEL 6.4)

Tags: rhel, yum, python

When I run `$ yum` I see:

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1: symbol EVP_aes_128_ctr, version libcrypto.so.10 not defined in file libcrypto.so.10 with link time reference

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.6.6 (r266:84292, Oct 12 2012, 14:23:48) 
[GCC 4.4.6 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

I updated Python and now if I run `$ python --version` I see `Python 2.7.12rc1`. But this doesn't match the current version, according to the error. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How did you update Python without yum? Have you installed any software not via the package manager?

Comment: @Wieland I downloaded a gzipped source and installed with `./configure`, 
`make`, and `sudo make install`

Comment: Not much you can do : python-2.6.6 cannot be "updated". `yum` and all the `system-config-*` tools depend on  python-2.6.6 . However, you can always install extra versions of python to a hidden location. Solution for your issues : Install / reinstall the OS. The free version is "Redhat CentOS 6.8" http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/centos.org/6.8/isos/x86_64/CentOS-6.8-x86_64-LiveCD.iso , then you don't have to leave the OS unsafe, but can do updates. ( RHEL 6.4 was released 2013.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better way without having to re-install your OS would be to download the python package (and possibly any python modules package) and use `rpm` to install them over your upgraded Python.

The python package for RHEL 6 should be `python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64` which should be available from Red Hat or you can pull it off a RHEL6 .iso file. You will probably have to use the `--force` option on the RPM as it has to override the package and any files.

After that `yum` should work though some cruft will still exist from the Python upgrade. When upgrading Python make sure that you use `--prefix` to install it somewhere like: `/usr/local/python2.7.12` or any where away from the system's Python files.